# In Formatting features for Rich Text Field when is the Filtering XSLT applied?

Tags: editor, tridion

I am trying to extract the value attribute of XML tag in Tridion rich text editor.

I am trying to add this code to filtering XSLT. But it is not working.

```
<xsl:template match="dynamicVariable">
    <dynamicVariable name="{//dynamicVariable/@name}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you can give a more concrete example of what you are trying to achieve. I believe the XSLT is applied when you paste content into the field, when you change tabs (from source to design) and when you save.

Comment: I am trying to add this code to filtering XSLT. But it is not working.
 <xsl:template match="dynamicVariable"> <dynamicVariable name="{//dynamicVariable/@name}"/> </xsl:template>

Comment: Can you please include your complete RTF source XHTML and your complete Filter XSLT. It seems like your code fragment essentially recreates an element that already exists in your RTF field1, and copies the name attribute (and ignores others). Is that what you are trying to do?